# Looping through multiple arrays and converting values using moment JS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a function that takes an object, re-sorts the days manually, and converts a string to an array

```
export const convertHoursOfOperation = (service) => {
  const hours = {
    Monday: service.hours_of_operation["monday"],
    Tuesday: service.hours_of_operation["tuesday"],
    Wednesday: service.hours_of_operation["wednesday"],
    Thursday: service.hours_of_operation["thursday"],
    Friday: service.hours_of_operation["friday"],
    Saturday: service.hours_of_operation["saturday"],
    Sunday: service.hours_of_operation["sunday"]
  };

  for (let hour in hours) {
    hours[hour] !== null ? hours[hour] = hours[hour].split(",") : hours[hour] = 'Closed'

    hours[hour] !== 'Closed' ? hours[hour].forEach((h) => moment(h, "HH:mm").format('h:mm')) : null
  }

  return hours;
}
```

output from `hours[hour] !== null ? hours[hour] = hours[hour].split(",") : hours[hour] = 'Closed'`

`monday: '09:00, 15:00' => monday: [09:00, 15:00]`
**OR** `monday: null => monday: 'Closed'`

then I am trying to loop through the array if it is an array and convert the values from military to standard time using `moment`.

so now my desired output should be:

```
monday: [09:00, 15:00] => monday: [9:00, 3:00]
```

currently the line `hours[hour] !== 'Closed' ? hours[hour].forEach((h) => moment(h, "HH:mm").format('h:mm')) : null` is not converting anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You don't appear to be setting your `moment()` to anything. you are simply running the function. Try like the line above it: `hours[hour] !== 'Closed' ? hours[hour].forEach((h) => hours[hour] = moment(h, "HH:mm").format('h:mm')) : null;`

Comment: At this point anything that is not 'closed' returns ```undefined```

Comment: Where is it returning that?

Comment: @Aditya that has worked! You may submit as answer if you'd like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not setting your `moment()` to anything. Set the value at that particular index. The correct code should be this:

```
hours[hour] !== 'Closed' ? hours[hour].forEach((h,index) => hours[hour][index] = moment(h, "HH:mm").format('h:mm')) : null;
```